# NHibernate 4 child collection saved, but not re-loaded

Tags: nhibernate

I've got an NHibernate 4 project with several collection relationships. I'm unit-testing the object model, exercising all the collections. Most work fine, but in one case, the child collection is cascade-saved properly, but on loading the parent entity and examining the collection property, the child collection is empty.

Here are the abbreviated classes.  GatewayUser is the parent object, and it has a collection of Student. The collection has a private backing property, and AddStudent/RemoveStudent methods.

Further complications: I'm using the NHibernate.AspNet.Identity library for OAuth2 user management, and GatewayUser inherits from IdentityUser. That in turn inherits from the the library's internal base entity class, which is different from my project's own base class.

public class GatewayUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public GatewayUser()
        {
        }

```
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    // ...More value properties and OAuth stuff omitted

    // students associated with this user
    private IList<Student> _students = new List<Student>();

    public virtual IList<Student> Students
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Student>(_students); }
    }

    public virtual GatewayUser AddStudent(Student s)
    {
        if (_students.Contains(s))
            return this;

        s.GatewayUser = this;
        _students.Add(s);
        return this;
    }

    public virtual GatewayUser RemoveStudent(Student s)
    {
        if (_students.Contains(s))
        {
            _students.Remove(s);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Student is more ordinary; it inherits from my own BaseEntity class, has many value properties, and its own child collection of ProgramApplication items. Interestingly, this collection saves and loads fine; it's got the same structure (private backer, etc.) as the failing collection in GatewayUser.

The mapping is complicated, because the library internally maps its classes with NHiberante.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist classes (which I have no prior experience with).
I'm mapping my own classes with NHibernate automapping, because I have so many classes and properties to map. To get it all working, I copied the library's mapping helper class, and modified it a bit to add my base entity classes to it's list called baseEntityToIgnore. I also had to create a conformist mapping for GatewayUser, since it has a different base entity type, and my automapping wouldn't pick it up.

The unit test looks like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void GatewayUserCascadesStudents()
    {

        var u = new GatewayUser() { FirstName = "Mama", LastName = "Bear", UserName = "somebody@example.com" };
        var s1 = new Student() { FirstName = "First", LastName = "Student" };
        var s2 = new Student() { FirstName = "Second", LastName = "Student" };

        u.AddStudent(s1).AddStudent(s2);

        using (var s = NewSession())
        using (var tx = s.BeginTransaction())
        {
            s.Save(u);
            tx.Commit();
        }

        GatewayUser fetched = null;
        int count = 0;
        using (var s = NewSession())
        {
            fetched = s.Get<GatewayUser>(u.Id);
            count = fetched.Students.Count;
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(2, count);
    }
```

The generated SQL inserts into both AspNetUsers and GatewayUser (reflecting the inheritance relationship), and inserts two records into Student. All good. On fetching, the SELECT joins the two user tables, and I get a GatewayUser object, but accessing the Students collection does not trigger a SELECT on the Student table. But if I change the mapping to Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy), the SQL to select eagerly load Students appears in the log, but the collection is not populated.  If I switch the database from SQLite to Sql Server, I see the student records in the table. The generated SQL (when NoLazy is applied) will fetch them. So on the database end, things look fine.

I have to think my Frankenstein mapping situation is to blame. I'm mixing the library's conformist mapping with Fluent mapping, and there are two different base entity classes. However, the generated schema looks correct, and the save cascades correctly, so I don't know if that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer.  My mapping of the parent class's list was like this:

public class GatewayUserMap : JoinedSubclassMapping
    {
        public GatewayUserMap()
        {
            Key(g => g.Column("Id"));
            Property(c => c.FirstName, m => m.Length(50));
            // ... more properties

```
        List(gu => gu.Students, map =>
        {
            map.Key(c => c.Column("GatewayUser_Id"));
            map.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
            map.Index(li => li.Column("ListIndex"));
            map.Access(Accessor.Field | Accessor.NoSetter);
        }
        );
    }
}
```

I have a private backing field for the collection. Removing Accessor.NoSetter from the collection mapping fixed it. In fact, it still worked without Accessor.Field -- I guess the mapper does a good job of looking around for one, and using it if found.  Changing the name of the private backer from "_students" to "funnyName" prevented the mapper from finding it.